# toLocaleDateString don't work in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

How to make toLocaleDateString compatible with TypeScript, I am tying to get the current day in number and the only way to convert to numeric is to use to local string which is not compatible with date, I tried to make a separate function instead of chaining but it is not working?

```
let currentDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()).valueOf().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' })
```

Comment: Try removing the .valueOf()

Comment: The use of *new Date* and various *get* methods is redundant, as is *Date* within *toLocaleDateString*. An identical result is achieved by `today.toLocaleString('en', {day: 'numeric'})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is compatible with TypeScript. Delete the `.valueOf()`. You are converting to a number there, that's what's causing you problems.

```
let currentDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' })
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `toLocaleDateString` method belongs to the `Date` class. In your code you have converted it using `valueOf()`.

The following code returns the current day number of today:

```
let currentDay = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' })
```